# Drupal Sub form

Tags: drupal

I have a question in drupal
I want to make a content type that have a title and body and a subform that contain a title and image and video and date and I can add more than one subform
I have searched for this module but after making a custom modules using field hooks API My site does not work again I don't no if I have an error or not
but there is no syntax error at all but after adding my field and saving data the site does not work

Does any one have a good tutorial for that
Hope you can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the module field collection http://drupal.org/project/field_collection With field collection you can add in collection some fields like: title , picture and video. Then you add the collection in the principal form.